# Encrypt a CSV column via UDF, Spark - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to encrypt a column in my `CSV` file. I am trying to do that using UDF. But I am getting compilation error. Here is my code :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, udf}

val upperUDF1 = udf { str: String => Encryptor.aes(str) }

val rawDF = spark
      .read
      .format("csv")
      .option("header", "true")
      .load(inputPath)

rawDF.withColumn("id", upperUDF1("id")).show() //Compilation error.
```

I am getting the compilation error in the last line, am I using the incorrect syntax. Thanks in advance.
[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should send a `Column` not a `String`, you can reference to a column by different syntaxes:

```scala
$"<columnName>" 
col("<columnName>")
```

So you should try this:

```
rawDF.withColumn("id", upperUDF1($"id")).show()
```

or this:

```
rawDF.withColumn("id", upperUDF1(col("id"))).show()
```

Personally i like the dollar syntax the most, seems more elegant to me

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer from SCouto, you could also register your udf as a Spark SQL function by

```scala
spark.udf.register("upperUDF2", upperUDF1)
```

Your subsequent select expression could then look like this

```scala
rawDF.selectExpr("id", "upperUDF2(id)").show()
```